# css animate fadeIn doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/9w0v62fa/1/

I don't want to use opacity 0 and 1 in two different  place, that's too redundant for me, so I try to use css animate property. But I coudln't make it work. My code seems ok for me, here are them.

```
.btn{
    background:blue;
    padding:10px;
    width:110px;
    color:white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.icon:before{
    content: url("http://w2.aic.edu/design/32png/imgur.png");
        -webkit-animation:fadeIn;
        animation:fadeIn;

}

@keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

My js

```
$(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $('div').addClass('icon');
    });
});
```

Comment: You doesn't provide any duration for animation and btw needs some vendor prefix for keyframe depending browser, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/9w0v62fa/3/

Comment: Sorry, I don't saw your comment  @A.Wolff

Comment: @tomloprod Don't worry, i prefer to comment instead of answer it because obviously OP didn't has checked the DOC

Comment: Yes, obviously. Also you can see that I have not "copied" your comment; my JSFiddle is earlier.

Comment: @tomloprod Absolutely ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff human makes mistake bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `duration` for animation. And you need to use `@-webkit-keyframes` for **webkit browsers**.

**CSS affected:**

```
.icon:before{
    content: url("http://w2.aic.edu/design/32png/imgur.png");
   -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s;
    animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
} 
@keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/9w0v62fa/2/